# Authlogic session model not binding to members model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authlogic

I am the getting the following error when hitting my home page. I've spent hours trying to figure it out with no luck. Looking at the debug output it seems that the member_session object is not picking up any of the methods available on the member object class.

This page contains two forms, one for registering and one for logging in.

```
 NoMethodError in Members#new

    Showing /home/thomas/railsProjects/draughtsWorld/app/views/common/_loginPanel.html.erb where line #23 raised:

    Model MemberSession does not respond to nickname

    Extracted source (around line #23):

    20:                     
    21:      <div class="">
    22:         <%= f.label :nickname, "Nickname" %>
    23:         <%= f.text_field :nickname, :class => "sign_in_textbox" %>
    24:       </div>          
    25:      
    26:       <div class="">

    Trace of template inclusion: app/views/members/new.html.erb

    Rails.root: /home/thomas/railsProjects/draughtsWorld
    Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

    app/views/common/_loginPanel.html.erb:23:in `block in _app_views_common__login_anel_html_erb__835376200_89586240__736259602'
    app/views/common/_loginPanel.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_common__login_anel_html_erb__835376200_89586240__736259602'
    app/views/members/new.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_members_new_html_erb___591788923_89768980__1034002099'
    app/controllers/members_controller.rb:33:in `new'
```

---

member.rb

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic
end
```

---

member_session.rb

```
class MemberSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
end
```

---

members_controller.rb:

```
class MembersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /members
  # GET /members.xml
  def index
    @members = Member.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @members }
    end
  end

  # GET /members/new
  # GET /members/new.xml
  def new
    @member = Member.new
    @member_session = MemberSession.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @member }
    end
  end
```

---

member_sessions_controller.rb:

```
class MemberSessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @member_session = MemberSession.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @member_session }
    end
  end

    def create
      @member_session = MemberSession.new(params[:member_session])
      if @member_session.save
        redirect_to root_url
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        #render :action => :new
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @member_session = MemberSession.find
      @member_session.destroy
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

---

loginPanel.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @member_session, :html => { :class => "block" } do |f| %>

      <%= debug(@member)%>
      <%= debug(@member_session.methods)%>

      <h4>Already Signed Up?</h4>

      <% if @member_session.errors.any? %>
        <ul>
          <% @member_session.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <% end %>

     <div class="">
        <%= f.label :nickname, "Nickname" %>
        <%= f.text_field :nickname, :class => "sign_in_textbox" %>
      </div>          

      <div class="">
        <%= f.label :password, "Password" %>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :class => "sign_in_textbox" %>
      </div> 

      <p class="submit">
        <%= f.submit "Login", :class => "submit_button" %>
      </p>

      <p class="lost_password">
        <a href="">Forgot you login details?</a>
      </p>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer:

> Model MemberSession does not respond to nickname

Does Member has column `nickname`?

I think this it should be either `username` or `login`, so try to change yours view to:

```
<%= f.label :username, "Nickname" %>
<%= f.text_field :username, :class => "sign_in_textbox" %>
```

or

```
<%= f.label :login, "Nickname" %>
<%= f.text_field :login, :class => "sign_in_textbox" %>
```

EDIT:
Or you can try to specify column name in authlogic configuration:

```
acts_as_authentic do |c|
  c.login_field = :nickname
end
```

It should do the job.

Comment: You can change column, or tell authlogic what your login column name is. I edited my answer to write, how to do it.

Comment: Hi tjeden. Yes member has 'nickname', I added it when generating the members scaffold and migrating to db. It works fine when registering the member in the same page. Is there somewhere I can check the code of what activeRecord generated? Are you saying I have to call that column login or username for it to work with authlogic? 
I'll try making all those suggestions later today when I get a chance. Hopefully it works :)

Comment: Specifying the column in the authlogic configuration worked tjeden. Thanks again